# Ajax custom parameter list

Tags: jquery, ajax, parameters, customization

How it is possible to customize the parameter list in an ajax call.

i.e.

At times this:

```
$.ajax({  url: TheURL, data: { par1:VAR_A, par2:VAR_B, par3:VAR_C} });
```

At other times this:

```
$.ajax({  url: TheURL, data: { par4:VAR_D, par5:VAR_E} });
```

And at other times this:

```
$.ajax({  url: TheURL, data: { par6:VAR_F} });
```

etc.

Thanks,

David

Comment: I don't see the problem. Just put the parameter list in a variable, and assign whatever you want to the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the parameters in a variable.

```
var params = { par1:VAR_A, par2:VAR_B, par3:VAR_C};
// or
var params = { par4:VAR_D, par5:VAR_E};
// or
var params = { par6:VAR_F};

$.ajax({  url: TheURL, data: params });
```

You could put your AJAX call in a function, then call it with the appropriate parameters:

```
function do_ajax(params) {
  $.ajax({  url: TheURL, data: params });
}
do_ajax({ par6:VAR_F});
// or
do_ajax({ par4:VAR_D, par5:VAR_E});
```

Comment: `par1: x`, what's the problem?

Comment: You seem to be making something complicated that's not, or there's more to this question that I'm not really understanding.

Comment: Do you need to construct the parameters dynamically?

Comment: I updated the answer, but it's not really much of a change.

Comment: All I did was copy your objects with the variables in them. Is there more to it that you're not explaining?